# Publish and save specific postmeta to a filtered post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have multiple plugins with different post_type(s). When I save or publish, all of the `custom_post_meta` that belong to one specific `post_type` are also saving.

I'd like to filter by `post_type` so that the `custom_post_meta` will only save in a specific `post_type`.

So my question is, if you have multiple plugins:

**How do you save a specific postmeta** to a specific `post_type`?

Would you just say:

```
if (post_type=="my_post_type") {
  add_action('save_post','save_my_meta_box_to_postmeta');
  add_action('publish_post','save_my_meta_box_to_postmeta');
}
```

And how do you **get** the `post_type` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the check inside the callback. `save_post` will [pass you both the post ID and the post object](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post.php#L2947):

```
do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
```

So...

```
function save_my_meta_box_to_postmeta($post_ID, $post) {
  if ('yourtype' === $post->post_type) {
    echo '<pre>';
      var_dump($post_ID,$post);
    echo '</pre>';
    die;
  }
}
add_action('save_post','save_my_meta_box_to_postmeta',1,2);
```

You may want other conditionals as well like `!DOING_AJAX`, for example.

Comment: I kept on targeting `save_post`, `edit_post`, and `publish_post`. Does not work. In my observation, `do_action('save_post',$post_ID,$post)` only seem to be applicable if `$post_ID` and `$post` are given inside the variable of `wp_insert_post` function. By not working, I mean `$post->post_type` does not seem to return any value inside `save_post` when used in a conditional statement.

Comment: Awesome... it finally worked! I made sure that `$priority` and `$accepted_args` inside `add_action` were populated. Then, everything went well. Thanks.